# How to "extend" a class so its variables can return a prefix with the value

Tags: c#, class, variables, getter

First of all sorry for the confusing title, I could not find the exact words to describe the situation. But it's easy to understand with an example.

We have a static class that holds the table names as a catalog like this:

```
public static class Tables
{
    public const string Employees= "DBEmploy1";
    public const string Sales = "Sale1";
    // (...etc)
}
```

And use them in our code like this:

```
string sql = "select name, surname from " + Tables.Employees + " where code='1'"
```

But sometimes we need to prefix the database connection or another prefix/suffix to the tables. The current solution is to declare a second Table catalog:

```
public static class CurrentDB1Prefix = "[databasex].dbo."

public static class Tables
{
    public const string Employees = "DBEmploy1";
    public const string Sales = "Sale1";
    // (...etc)
}
public static class TablesP
{
    public static readonly string Employees = CurrentDB1Prefix + Employees;
    public static readonly string Sales = CurrentDB1Prefix + Sales;
    // (...etc)
}
```

And use them in our code like:

```
string sql = "select name, surname from " + TablesP.Employees + " where code='1'"
```

To save effort maintaining two table lists we would like to do something like this:

```
public static class CurrentDB1Prefix = "[databasex].dbo."
public static class Tables
{
    public const string Employees= "DBEmploy1";
    public const string Sales = "Sale1";
    // (...etc)
}
public static class TablesP
{
    //this would return the above Table class variables with the prefixes somehow
    return CurrentDB1Prefix + Table.TableVariablex;
}
```

How can this be done? Or some approximation as usable as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `static` and don't use `const`. Make the values runtime-changable by converting the fields to properties. Like this:

```
public class Tables
{
  public string CurrentPrefix = ...;
  public string Employees { get { return CurrentPrefix  + "DBEmploy1" };
  //(...etc)
}
```

Comment: The important thing is that we want to have the 2 options, Tables to get the table names without prefix and TablesP to get them with Prefix (doing mainteinance only in the first one)

Comment: @ase69s what'S preventing you from doing that? Either create a 2nd class TablesP, or make the properties methods that take a `bool applyPrefix` argument.

Comment: Being something semiconstant (the current prefix is only assigned at program start and not changed later) i wanted to use the most lightweight option (like const) so it doesn't have to calculate it at each access to the second class, also i wanted to assure that each variable in the first class has a counterpart in the second class (like when you use abstract or interfaces that warns you if you don't implement its child elements)

Comment: You can compute the values once int the ctor and store them in readonly fields. You can't use const for non-compiletime constants.; With the code I posted you can have an instance that has a prefix of "" which will result in no prefix. If that happens to be not enough, you could create a small class hierarchy with an abstract base class that defines the required members.